# Какова поддержка браузерами методов SVG api?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

Заинтересовался рисованием и морфингом путей в SVG. [MS упоминают](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff971907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) много методов вроде `createSVGPathSegCurvetoCubicAbs()`, но Mozilla пока [не документировала](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement) часть таких методов, хотя поддерживает в десктоп версии.

Какова сейчас поддержка (мобильными) браузерами интерфейса [`InterfaceSVGPathElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathElement)?

P.s. [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/) ничего не находит при поиске по "createSVGPathSegCurvetoCubicAbs".

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: Такие вещи надо брать и проверять. Ну и перебирать грабли.

Comment: меня интересуют мобильные браузеры и методы вроде `createSVGPathSegCurvetoCubicAbs()`